# Getting error "Creating data source failed" (20609) - in Crystal Report 7 and VB6.0 while connecting to Informix database server using ODBC DSN

Tags: vba, ms-access, crystal-reports, vb6, informix

The system was having two databases connection, one is with the MS Access database and the other was IBM's Informix database. The Crystal Reports were working fine with the MS Access Database. Now we have removed the dependency on MS Access and moved all the tables into Informix. While migrating the data, the table names were changed. The database was changed in the report from the menu **Database > Add Database to report** and the old database was removed using menu **Database > Remove from report**. The database driver has been converted to 'pdsodbc.dll [ODBC]' using the menu **Database > Convert database driver...**

Post that I am getting an error in vb6 code.

**Error description:** Creating data source failed.

**Error code:** 20609

My code in the vb is as follows:

```
CrystalReport1.WindowTitle = "Embosser/Encoder Report"
CrystalReport1.ReportFileName = App.path & "\Rpt3.rpt"
CrystalReport1.Connect = "DSN=" & DSN & ";Database=rbtt;UID=" & remlog & ";PWD=" & rempass & "; Persist Security Info=False"
CrystalReport1.Formulas(0) = "bank = ' " & Mainfrm.StatusBar1.Panels(2) & " ' "
CrystalReport1.Formulas(1) = "user = 'User Name: " & useN & " ' "
CrystalReport1.Formulas(2) = "title = 'Embosser/Encoder Report'"

stop_len = format(param3, "00")
start_len = format(param1, "00")
local_card_len = format(local_card_len, "00")
CrystalReport1.Formulas(3) = "lens = '" & local_card_len & start_len & stop_len & " ' "

CrystalReport1.SQLQuery = sql
CrystalReport1.WindowState = crptMaximized
CrystalReport1.Action = 1
```

I am getting the error when the line **CrystalReport1.Action** = 1 is executed.
The variable **sql** contains an sql query which has all the columns required in the report.
The variable **DSN** has the DSN name which is configured in the ODBC.
The variables **remlog** and **rempass** have the username and password required to connect to the server. Other details like server ip are mentioned in the DSN.

Comment: Can you check that the DSN is working (outside CrystalReports) and that you are using the same arch (32-bits vs 64-bits)?  
If your CrystalReports is 32-bit you need a 32-bit Informix ODBC driver, otherwise it will not work. Check the suffix of your Client SDK (e.g. run the Informix setnet32.exe tool and go to the 'About setnet32' tab). Anything ending with a '.FCxx' is 64-bit, with a '.TCxx' is 32-bit

Comment: Just checked online. 1998 CrystalReports 7 had two flavours, 16-bit and 32-bit, so forget about 64-bit ;)